# Delete non-unique group with group ID as primary group of a user

Tags: group

So say I have two groups with names **testing1** and **testing2**. Both groups have the same group ID of 2000. Then I add a user named *testing-user* with GID of 2000. Along the way I want to delete group testing2, but I cannot because when I try I get the following response

```
groupdel: cannot remove the primary group of user 'testing-user'
```

Here are the methods I have tried around this to success:

- Modified testing1's GID and then deleted testing2, then changed testing1's GID back to 2000
- Modified testing-user's primary GID to a separate group, deleted testing2 then assigned testing-user to testing1

Is there a better method for this that does not involve modifying the users or group id's in question?

Comment: In fact, there's several problem here, first two group with the same GID, second, you're question is in my opinion more about opinion because you create a non logical situation and try to find the "best possible solution"...

Comment: On which Unix OS are you doing this ? Are you using locally defined users and groups or some kind of external backend like LDAP or NIS(+) ?

Comment: Nope, just working locally on Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're getting is a limitation of the way **groupdel** was written and the fact that the system is designed around numbers (IDs) and not names. As you can see in [source code](http://anonscm.debian.org/gitweb/?p=pkg-shadow/shadow.git;a=blob;f=src/groupdel.c;h=bdadf7d373f3106333e6ca34f7605dcf15cf13ac;hb=db1dc7288b64873f4f39e8404fd99c1bf55c7a8b#l269) of **groupdel**, it only checks if there's a user having the GID you want to delete, as its primary group. It doesn't matter if there's another group having the same ID, but named differently.

```
/* [ Note: I changed the style of the source code for brevity purposes. ]
 * group_busy - check if this is any user's primary group
 *
 *      group_busy verifies that this group is not the primary group
 *      for any user.  You must remove all users before you remove
 *      the group.
 */
static void group_busy (gid_t gid)
{
        struct passwd *pwd;

        /* Nice slow linear search. */
        setpwent ();
        while ( ((pwd = getpwent ()) != NULL) && (pwd->pw_gid != gid) )
                ;
        endpwent ();

        /* If pwd isn't NULL, it stopped because the gid's matched. */
        if (pwd == (struct passwd *) 0)
                return;

        /* Can't remove the group. */
        fprintf (stderr,
                 _("%s: cannot remove the primary group of user '%s'\n"),
                 Prog, pwd->pw_name);
        exit (E_GROUP_BUSY);
}
```

So you either you mess with the configuration files using other tools like Perl in [mtm's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/139034/1174) or you temporarily change the GID of that user so that `group_busy` doesn't fail anymore.

Answer (score 2):

This is not that safe as you should always use the provided utilities to modify users are groups but...

```
[ ! -f /etc/group.lock ] && perl -ne 'next if /^testing2:/; print' /etc/group > /etc/group.lock && mv /etc/group.lock /etc/group && grpconv
```

Comment: What about `/etc/gshadow`?

Answer (score 0):

The default group of any user, at least on Gentoo, is to have the group name the same as the user name.  If you create a group and put a user in it, when removed, the user will belong to the group of his username.